# Nuxt application taking more than 4 minutes to compile

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm building a Nuxt application. I've done some research but found no definitive solution.

I've found a GitHub issue with something similar (https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3486) but wasn't able to find a definitive solution:

[image]

It was compiling "normally", not taking more than 1 minute. I've just added around 300 lines of html to a Vue component. Suddenly went extremely low.

There are no explicit errors, alerts or warning messages, only the performance went extremely low. How to track this performance decrease?

So this is the nuxt.config.js file

```
const pkg = require('./package')
const webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  debug: true,
  prettify: false,
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    script: [
      { src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8" },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  buildDir: '../functions/nuxt',

  build:{
    publicPath: '/',
    vendor: ['axios','firebase', "jquery", 'popper', "bootstrap", 'bootbox'],
    extractCSS: true,
    babel: {
      presets: [
        'es2015',
        'stage-0'
      ],
      plugins: [

        [
          "transform-runtime",
          {
           "polyfill":true,
           "regenerator":true
          },
          "~/plugins/firebase.js",
          "~/plugins/bootboxPlugin.js"
        ],
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          jQuery: 'jquery',
          $: 'jquery',
          jquery: 'jquery'
        })
      ]

    },
    prettify: false
  },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [

  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */

  build: {
    prettify: false,
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'eval-source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
      prettify = false
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure where the prettify : false directive should go, so I've tried in many places, because I'm not sure where the vueLoader is happening.

Also in the Nuxt documentation says

> Note: This config has been removed since Nuxt 2.0, please use build.loaders.vue instead.

So this made me more confused. Where this build.loaders.vue is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its not nuxt fault. Blame the prettier. Here is issue that is causing this: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4784

Solutions:

1) Dont use large nested template, split it into several components -> thats a best solution from terms of code quality

2) Set `prettify: false` in the `loaders` options

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#loaders

https://github.com/vuejs/component-compiler-utils/blob/master/lib/compileTemplate.ts#L173

example nuxt config

```
export default {
  build: {
    loaders:  {
      vue: {
         prettify: false
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hello there @Aldarun, where in the nuxt.config.js file should prettify: false should go?
I´ve edited my question to show the nuxt.config.js file. I´ve put the prettify false in all places I could find, but still the build time is extremely slow...

Comment: @AdrielWerlich if u read the linked nuxt doc u should see where it should go... I have updated my answer. But i strongly suggest to go way 1. Also using jquery in nuxt porject is a bad idea too

Comment: @Aldarund - if using Jquery in Nuxt is a bad idea, the answer shouldn't be "don't use jquery", it should be "Nuxt should integrate jquery." From all the frameworks I've built production grade web apps, up until today NO SOUL came to create a plugin so powerful as jquery.

Comment: What exactly does setting `prettify: false` do?

Answer (score 4):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author, to move it to the answer space)*.

So the final solution is this

## nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports { //or export default {

build: {
    publicPath: '/',
    vendor: ['axios','firebase', "jquery", 'popper', "bootstrap", 'bootbox'],
    extractCSS: true,
    babel: {
      presets: [
        'es2015',
        'stage-0'
      ],
      plugins: [

        [
          "transform-runtime",
          {
           "polyfill":true,
           "regenerator":true
          },
          "~/plugins/firebase.js",
          
          new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
          })
        ],
        
      ]

    },
    // adding the below object made the compilation time go up again to 
    //"normal" 
    loaders:  {
      vue: {
        prettify: false
      }
    },
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'eval-source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
      
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks for @Aldarund for the support.